# Does BQL allow for DatePart?

Tags: acumatica

I have a bql aggregate query that I want to group by the Year and the Month.
This would be simple enough in SQL, but not so obvious in BQL.

The table (DAC) has a date field in it.
If I group by the date field alone, it basically gives me each individual record.
I would like to group on the year in the date and the month in the date.

Does BQL have the ability to grab the DATEPART like in SQL and group by that DATEPART result?

I see it has a datediff function, but no documentation on what I would like to do.

Comment: Is this for grouping data on an existing Acumatica table or a table you have created?

Comment: This is for grouping on a date within a custom table, although I would like to be able to use it on any date field where I might want to aggregate data.

Comment: Max gave you a very nice sample, other option would have been to have a text field containing YYYYMM in your custom table that you would have populated yourself. This is how I would  have done it to avoid the need to write a custom BQL operand

Comment: I agree, the layout of that table is laid in stone at this point though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this works for you:

```
public sealed class DatePart
{
    public const string Day = "dd";
    public const string Hour = "hh";
    public const string Minute = "mi";
    public const string Month = "mm";
    public const string Year = "yyyy";
    public const string Second = "ss";
    public const string Millisecond = "ms";

    public class day : Constant<string> { public day() : base(Day) { } }
    public class hour : Constant<string> { public hour() : base(Hour) { } }
    public class minute : Constant<string> { public minute() : base(Minute) { } }
    public class month : Constant<string> { public month() : base(Month) { } }
    public class year : Constant<string> { public year() : base(Year) { } }
    public class second : Constant<string> { public second() : base(Second) { } }
    public class millisecond : Constant<string> { public millisecond() : base(Millisecond) { } }
}


public sealed class DatePart<UOM, Operand> : BqlFunction, IBqlOperand, IBqlCreator
    where Operand: IBqlOperand
    where UOM : Constant<string>, new()
{
    private IBqlCreator _operand;

    public void Verify(PXCache cache, object item, List<object> pars, ref bool? result, ref object value)
    {
        value = null;
        object date1;
        if (!getValue<Operand>(ref _operand, cache, item, pars, ref result, out date1) || date1 == null) return;


        DateTime period = Convert.ToDateTime(date1);
        switch ((string)new UOM().Value)
        {
            case DatePart.Day:
                value = Convert.ToInt32(period.Day);
                break;
            case DatePart.Hour:
                value = Convert.ToInt32(period.Hour);
                break;
            case DatePart.Minute:
                value = Convert.ToInt32(period.Minute);
                break;
            case DatePart.Second:
                value = Convert.ToInt32(period.Second);
                break;
            case DatePart.Millisecond:
                value = Convert.ToInt32(period.Millisecond);
                break;
            case DatePart.Month:
                value = Convert.ToInt32(period.Month);
                break;
            case DatePart.Year:
                value = Convert.ToInt32(period.Year);
                break;
        }
    }


    public void Parse(PXGraph graph, List<IBqlParameter> pars, List<Type> tables, List<Type> fields,
                      List<IBqlSortColumn> sortColumns, StringBuilder text, BqlCommand.Selection selection)
    {
        if (graph != null && text != null)
        {
            text.Append(" DATEPART(").Append((string)new UOM().Value).Append(", ");
            parseOperand<Operand>(ref _operand, graph, pars, tables, fields, sortColumns, text, selection);
            text.Append(")");
        }
        else
        {
            parseOperand<Operand>(ref _operand, graph, pars, tables, fields, sortColumns, text, selection);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: this is specific for MsSQL and won't work for mySQL.

Comment: Nice example of how to create a custom BQL operand. Thanks Max!